# automatic time element js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, time

I have just made a from for a warehouse, but I do not feel that the workers should have to fill out the date+time every time, is there any way I can automatically fill a hidden input with the time, using js? I would like the full date+time like this: DD/MM/YYYY H:MM
this is my code:

```html
<html>
<iframe src ="adminview.html" scrolling="no" height ="100"></iframe>
  <!--this is the date and time script I am using to try to fill the input-->
<script>
var today = new Date();
var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
</script>
<form action ="">
  Name of employee:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
  Item no.:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
  Quantity of item:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
<!--this is the input I am trying to fill with the above js-->
<input type ="hidden" value="UTCstring"></input>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: If it can't be set manually, why not just add the time on the server?

Comment: Is the intention behind pre-population of date/time is facilitation or like Ties ask is it fix and we can set it on server side? If its purely for better user experience than you can pre-populate it on document load

Comment: yes I goess you can do that on the server side,but I have never known hpw to do time in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your hidden input an id (Eg : dateField) and then add this to your script -

```
document.getElementById('dateField').value = UTCstring;
```

The above line finds your hidden Date field and sets the value in that. You can now use this value to populate your form with a default one.
(If you want to do it on the client side)

Here's the updated code

```html
<html>
<iframe src ="adminview.html" scrolling="no" height ="100"></iframe>
  <!--this is the date and time script I am using to try to fill the input-->
<script>
var today = new Date();
var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
document.getElementById('dateField').value = UTCstring; // or today.toUTCString();
</script>
<form action ="">
  Name of employee:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
  Item no.:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
  Quantity of item:<br>
<input type ="text"></input>
<!--this is the input I am trying to fill with the above js-->
<input id="dateField" type ="hidden"></input>
</form>
</html>
```